# Improve performance moving multiple wpf elements

Tags: wpf, vb.net, performance

Doing projects for fun helps me learn. Here is a project that I am working on and I have already learned so much. I would like to see the program be less CPU intensive though. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do that?

Basically this program just overlays some snow flakes onto a computer screen.

---

EDIT:

What I am currently taking a look into is to see if I can use DoubleAnimationUsingPath and bind to the PathGeometry. While I am trying to figure this out I welcome any suggestion or tips regarding this method or any other.

---

WPF/XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStyle="None"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Transparent" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Canvas Name="canvas1">

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

VB.NET Main Window:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

    Dim bw As New BackgroundWorker
    Dim flakes(17) As flake

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        For i = 0 To flakes.Count - 1
            flakes(i) = New flake
            flakes(i).image.DataContext = flakes(i)
            flakes(i).image.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, "left")
            flakes(i).image.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, "top")
            canvas1.Children.Add(flakes(i).image)
        Next

        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf backgroundMover
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub


    Private Sub backgroundMover()
        While (True)
            For Each f In flakes
                f.move()
            Next
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

VB.Net flake class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class flake
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Private Property startLeft As Double
    Private Property _left As Double
    Private Property _top As Double
    Private Property speed As Double
    Private Property amplitude As Double
    Private Property period As Double
    Public Property image As New Image
    Private Shared Property r As New Random

    Public Sub New()
        _image.Width = 28
        _image.Height = 26
        _image.Source = New System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri("/snowTest;component/Images/blue-pin-md.png", UriKind.Relative))
        startFresh()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property left As Double
        Get
            Return _left
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property top As Double
        Get
            Return _top
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub startFresh()
        _top = -30
        amplitude = r.Next(5, 35)
        period = 1 / r.Next(20, 60)
        speed = r.Next(15, 25) / 10
        startLeft = r.Next(0, System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)
    End Sub

    Public Sub move()
        If _top > System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight Then
            startFresh()
        Else
            _top += speed
            _left = amplitude * Math.Cos(period * _top) + startLeft
        End If

        NotifyPropertyChanged("top")
        NotifyPropertyChanged("left")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating LeftProperty and TopProperty on your UIElement inside the canvas forces a new layout pass for each update. Layout in WPF is pretty expensive from a performances point of view. You should use [UIElement.RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) Property instead.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion. I am looking into how to use UIElement.RenderTransform right now. If you have suggestions on how to implement that in my code above I would appreciate it.

Comment: In your case, a simple TranslateTransform (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx) should do the trick. Sorry, I don't have time to adapt your code (I'm really really bad with VB :) )

Comment: No worries, I appreciate any and all help. Don't worry about putting things in VB if you want to do it in C# I am sure I can figure it out. But really, pointing me in a direction to research is helpful.